# Responsive mode on desktop displays different than on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass, responsive

I have a small landing page, it still needs some work but I'm stuck on a line-height o margin or height or vertical-align problem.

Whenever I try it on a desktop browser(chrome, firefox) on responsive mode it displays okay but on mobile (both safari and firefox for andoroid) it breaks. It's as if the text aligns on top on mobile but I don't know how to solve it.

**HTML**

```
<section id="main-1">
<div class="container">
    <div id="claim">
        <h1>Bono de bienvenida</h1>
        <p class="huge">300€</p>
        <p>parajugar a casino</p>
        <p class="smaller">con el código: experto</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
$proportion: 9vmin;

#main-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-image: url('/dist/assets/img/img_768x1024.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;

  .container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #claim {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) 15%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46) 85%,
            rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
    font-size: $proportion * 12 / 12;
    line-height: $proportion * 12 / 12;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin-top: 0;


    .huge {
      font-size: $proportion * 55 / 12;
      line-height: $proportion * 39 / 12;
      margin-bottom: 0;

    }

    .smaller {
      font-size: $proportion * 6 / 12;
      text-transform: lowercase;
      line-height: $proportion * 4 / 12;
    }

  }
}
```

You can see it live at http://bienvenida.casinobarcelona.es

**What you see on desktop with responsive mode**

[image: What you see on desktop with responsive mode]

**What you actually see on mobile**
[image: What you actually see on mobile]

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries for this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 544px) {
#claim {line-height:2vw;} /* wanted line height etc */
.huge  {line-height:2vw;}
}
```

Untill you are satisfied with the result

Comment: What would that change?

Comment: @LNubiola Any code you write in here would change the layout only on devices less than 544px wide (mobile), so you can fix how it looks on mobile resolution without messing up the desktop layout.

Comment: I understand that. But the trouble I'm having is that when I use the responsive mode on desktop it looks good, but when i watch it on mobile it doesn't. And I can't find any property that is not supported by mobile so I can't solve it because I can't find the problem.

Comment: Try adding this code to head:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: It's already in there:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Is width on your phone less than minimal browser width on your desktop?